# issues with Oozie and Sqoop Export

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop, oozie

I am trying to do an Sqoop export, the sqoop command works just fine in the local Servers, however, when I try to use the same command as an Oozie action, I am getting the following error, any help would be appreciated.

```
<<< Invocation of Main class completed <<<

Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain], main() threw exception, org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.AcidUtils.isTablePropertyTransactional(Ljava/util/Map;)Z
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.AcidUtils.isTablePropertyTransactional(Ljava/util/Map;)Z
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.FosterStorageHandler.configureInputJobProperties(FosterStorageHandler.java:134)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HCatUtil.getInputJobProperties(HCatUtil.java:458)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InitializeInput.extractPartInfo(InitializeInput.java:161)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InitializeInput.getInputJobInfo(InitializeInput.java:137)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InitializeInput.setInput(InitializeInput.java:88)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatInputFormat.setInput(HCatInputFormat.java:95)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatInputFormat.setInput(HCatInputFormat.java:51)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities.configureHCat(SqoopHCatUtilities.java:349)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportJobBase.runExport(ExportJobBase.java:433)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SQLServerManager.exportTable(SQLServerManager.java:192)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.exportTable(ExportTool.java:81)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.run(ExportTool.java:100)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:225)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:243)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.runSqoopJob(SqoopMain.java:197)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.run(SqoopMain.java:179)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:58)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.main(SqoopMain.java:48)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:240)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1869)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164)

Oozie Launcher failed, finishing Hadoop job gracefully

Oozie Launcher, uploading action data to HDFS sequence file: hdfs://EAP-DR/user/sps_hpe_ibproetl/oozie-oozi/0005868-200326034412660-oozie-oozi-W/sqoop_2--sqoop/action-data.seq
7378 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.ZlibFactory  - Successfully loaded & initialized native-zlib library
7379 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool  - Got brand-new compressor [.deflate]
Successfully reset security manager from org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherSecurityManager@4440750 to null
```

Oozie Launcher ends

Answer (score 1):

When you run `sqoop` command from local it uses jars from `/usr/lib/sqoop/lib`.
And when you use oozie sqoop action it uses jars from `hdfs:///user/oozie/share/lib/lib_*/sqoop/`

Now looking at your error, you either are

1. Missing org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.AcidUtils on the classpath
2. Have the wrong version of org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.AcidUtils on the classpath
3. Have multiple versions of org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.AcidUtils on the classpath